# How to bind to UserControl DataContext from ItemsControl in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, avalonia

Here is my view:

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="250" d:DesignHeight="450"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Application.ViewModels;assembly=Application"
             x:DataType="vm:TaskListViewModel"
             x:Class="TaskTracker.Views.TaskListView">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                x:CompileBindings="False"
                Command="{Binding $parent[Window].DataContext.AddTask}">
            Add Item
        </Button>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="2">
                        <DockPanel Margin="10">
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="24"
                                       Text="{Binding Content}" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="{Binding TimeWasted}" />
                                <Button
                                    Command="{Binding }"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}">
                                    <PathIcon Data="{StaticResource play_circle_regular}" />
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In the most nested button I need to bind to UserControl's DataContext, but the current DataContext is Task because of ItemsControl. How can I reach TaskListViewModel from there?

I tried to do it with
`Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:TaskListViewModel}}}"`
but it didn't help

I also tried
`Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"`
but the DataContext was TaskListView instead of TaskListViewModel

Comment: Did you try `Command="{Binding $parent[Window].DataContext.YourCommand}"` just like in the button from the dock panel?

Comment: @radoslawik I've done it like this ```Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.StartTrackingCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"```. It works, but there must be additional parameter ```x:CompileBindings="False"``` on button